# Share .h file issue Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have 2 project (test and pods in the image) and my problem is this:

in the Test project I created a Today widget called `WidgetNotificationCenter` and in `TodayViewController.h` file I have to import a .h file which is located in the pods project, so when I try to import this .h in `TodayViewController.h` I get an error that tell me that it doesn't find this .h file.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Show us your `Podfile`. Most likely your pods are set up only for your main target and not for the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't have the pod available in extension target and your pods are defined for main target.
You can change your pod file like this

```
target '[Main App Target Name]' do
        pod ...
        pod ...
        pod ...
end

target '[Extension Target Name]' do
        pod ...
end
```